# How to stop tshark or tcpdump without `Unable to write output: Broken pipe` error?

Tags: bash, wireshark, tcpdump, packet-analyzer

I need to stop `tcpdump` or `tshark` loop based on a condition. Currently I'm using `break`.

```
while IFS= read -r line; do if [[ $line =~ 'some protocol' ]]; then echo $line; break; fi; done < <(sudo tcpdump)
```

or

```
while IFS= read -r line; do if [[ $line =~ 'some protocol' ]]; then echo $line; break; fi; done < <(sudo tshark)
```

How can I do that in a way I don't get the message `Unable to write output: Broken pipe`

Comment: Why do you not want to see the message when you do not know what the message means? If it was me I would be trying to understand the message not stop it.

Comment: I really need both man. I know that's an issue because it's causing a timeout in some environments, but I could not find much about the meaning so far. All I know is that after the message the terminal still keeps busy with some process. I really tried to understand the message before I came here.

Comment: think this summary at the end tries to write the pipe after it's closed. Could probably silence it with `tcpdump -l 2>/dev/null` or `unbuffer tcpdump -l`

Comment: I understood now. Thanks!

Comment: Could you please explain the options `-l 2>/dev/null`?